# Are there any naming conventions for aerial imagery?

Tags: imagery

Do GIS projects involving high resolution NAIP quarter quad imagery typically use the USGSID code and qq (e.g. 3910232ne) or the GNIS code and qq (e.g. 39102e1ne) to organize data?  I can't seem to find a consistent protocol.